# Inspect if webrtc connection is successfully established

Tags: webrtc, rtcpeerconnection

I've created a webrtc app on localhost. Because the input video and output video is coming from the same camera, I can't visually determine if the webrtc connection is indeed working correctly.

I went to `chrome://webrtc-internals/`, to inspect the details, but I am not sure which one tells me if connection is working. Is there some flag that I can check, perhaps on `RTCPeerConnection` object or in `webrtc-internals`, to determine if the connection is indeed successful?

Answer (score 2):

If the connection is established successfully, then you will be seeing this in chrome://webrtc-internals/

24/07/2019, 16:54:53
signalingstatechange
stable

and

24/07/2019, 16:55:09
iceconnectionstatechange
completed

[image]